# is dt is in milliseconds in the method -(void) update:(ccTime)dt

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

hiii

I am pretty new to cocos2d. I am going to count the time in seconds via **-(void) update:(ccTime)dt** method. please any one tell me the **dt** of **-(void) update:(ccTime)dt** method is in millisecond or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is equal to the FPS set in AppDelegate.m file.By default, It is been set to 1/60. That is 16.67 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ccTime type represents time in **seconds**.

But you'll usually receive values in the millisecond range, like `0.001`.